My footer is not sticking to the bottom of my page due to a dynamic table
Here is the html:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>-</title>
    <style>
        html, body {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            height: fit-content;
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
        }
        body {
            font-family: Agdasima, sans-serif;
            background-color: #324ebf;
            position: relative;
            height: fit-content;
        }
        header {
            background-color: #2b2189;
            color: white;
            padding: 10px;
            text-align: center;
            border-bottom: 4px solid #1a1358;
        }
        .container {
            width: 80%;
            margin: auto;
            padding: 20px;
            flex: 1 0 auto; /* Allow this section to grow */
            background-color: #324ebf;
        }
        .container h2 {
            color: white;
            text-align: center;
        }
        .song-table {
            width: 60%;
            max-width: 600px;
            margin: 20px auto;
            border-collapse: collapse;
            background-color: #ff69b4;
            font-size: 14px;
        }
        th, td {
            padding: 8px;
            text-align: left;
            border: 1px solid #8b004b;
        }
        th {
            background-color: #c71585;
            color: white;
        }
        td {
            background-color: #ff69b4;
            color: black;
        }
        .content-bottom-padding {
            padding-bottom: 50px; /* Adjust this as needed to create space */
        }
        footer {
            background-color: #2b2189;
            color: white;
            text-align: center;
            padding: 10px;
            border-top: 4px solid #1a1358;
            width: 100%;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<header>
    <h1>test</h1>
</header>

<div class="container content-bottom-padding">
    <h2>abc</h2>
    <div id="table-container">
        <!-- Placeholder for dynamically inserted table -->
    </div>
</div>

<footer>
    <p>xyz</p>
</footer>

</body>
</html>

I have tried editing the style.css and index.html a million ways but I cannot figure it out. The script I am using in Python uses pandas, beautiful soup, and requests.
In short terms, the script basically inputs data from another website in the form of a table. This table increases with the amount of data going into it. I believe this is what is causing the issue. Initially, I was having a problem where the footer was at the bottom of the page but just overlapping the table. Now, however, the issue is that the footer is just above the table entirely.

If you suspect this is in any way related to the Python part of your code, please [edit] your question to include the relevant Python. Otherwise, I'd advise removing the Python tag from the question.

It doesn't look like you're doing anything to position the footer currently, so it'll land where it lands. The easiest solution will be to add position: fixed; bottom: 0; to the #footer element; that'll fix it to the bottom of the viewport. The padding you already have in .content-bottom-padding looks like it was intended to provide room for the table to scroll all the way out from under a fixed-position footer.

This question is similar to: Fix footer to bottom of page. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Have you ensured your table markup isn't missing any closing tags?
It would help to see it.  This fiddle renders fine for me: https://jsfiddle.net/p76r8ztL/

Use fixed positioning for your footer.


html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: fit-content;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

body {
  font-family: Agdasima, sans-serif;
  background-color: #324ebf;
  position: relative;
  height: fit-content;
}

header {
  background-color: #2b2189;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  border-bottom: 4px solid #1a1358;
}

main {
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 20px;
  flex: 1 0 auto; /* Allow this section to grow */
  background-color: #324ebf;
  padding-bottom: 100px; /* Adjust this as needed to create space */
}

main h2 {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

.song-table {
  width: 60%;
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: 20px auto;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  background-color: #ff69b4;
  font-size: 14px;
}

th, td {
  padding: 8px;
  text-align: left;
  border: 1px solid #8b004b;
}

th {
  background-color: #c71585;
  color: white;
}

td {
  background-color: #ff69b4;
  color: black;
}

footer {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #2b2189;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
  border-top: 4px solid #1a1358;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
<header>
    <h1>header</h1>
</header>

<main>
  <h2>content</h2>
  <div id="table-container">
    <table class="song-table">
      <tr><td>a</td><td>b</td></tr>
      <tr><td>a</td><td>b</td></tr>
      <tr><td>a</td><td>b</td></tr>
      <tr><td>a</td><td>b</td></tr>
      <tr><td>a</td><td>b</td></tr>
      <tr><td>a</td><td>b</td></tr>
      <tr><td>a</td><td>b</td></tr>
      <tr><td>a</td><td>b</td></tr>
      <tr><td>a</td><td>b</td></tr>
      <tr><td>a</td><td>b</td></tr>
      <tr><td>a</td><td>b</td></tr>
      <tr><td>a</td><td>b</td></tr>
      <tr><td>a</td><td>b</td></tr>
      <tr><td>a</td><td>b</td></tr>
      <tr><td>a</td><td>b</td></tr>
      <tr><td>a</td><td>b</td></tr>
      <tr><td>a</td><td>b</td></tr>
      <tr><td>a</td><td>b</td></tr>
      <tr><td>a</td><td>b</td></tr>
      <tr><td>a</td><td>b</td></tr>
      <tr><td>a</td><td>b</td></tr>
      <tr><td>a</td><td>b</td></tr>
      <tr><td>a</td><td>b</td></tr>
      <tr><td>a</td><td>b</td></tr>
      <tr><td>a</td><td>b</td></tr>
      <tr><td>a</td><td>b</td></tr>
      <tr><td>a</td><td>b</td></tr>
      <tr><td>a</td><td>b</td></tr>
      <tr><td>a</td><td>b</td></tr>
      <tr><td>a</td><td>b</td></tr>
      <tr><td>a</td><td>b</td></tr>
      <tr><td>a</td><td>b</td></tr>
      <tr><td>a</td><td>b</td></tr>
      <tr><td>a</td><td>b</td></tr>
      <tr><td>a</td><td>b</td></tr>
      <tr><td>a</td><td>b</td></tr>
      <tr><td>a</td><td>b</td></tr>
      <tr><td>a</td><td>b</td></tr>
      <tr><td>a</td><td>b</td></tr>
      <tr><td>a</td><td>b</td></tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</main>

<footer>
    <p>footer</p>
</footer>




Thanks for that! The footer is now always showing on the screen, and it overlaps the dynamic table. Any tips for how I could make it below the table and only at the bottom of the page?

You need the bottom padding on the main content area (or any element which wraps the table) to be at least as big as the footer. In this snippet I have used main {padding-bottom: 100px;}.
